# Error executing Exception got executed only

Tags: php, html

I have created 4 input types name, price, description, brand and one input file type image. on being clicked on submit button i want all the 5 inputs to go into database table "product" but on submit being clicked it just displays the exception as output "Some of your fields are empty" but all fields are being filled. i can even provide the html code.

```
<?php
    // Do we have a Form Submission
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        try {

            // Check that all your fields have values
            if (
                (!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])) ||
                (!isset($_POST['desc']) || empty($_POST['desc'])) ||
                (!isset($_POST['price']) || empty($_POST['price'])) ||
                (!isset($_POST['brand']) || empty($_POST['brand'])) ||
                (!isset($_POST['image']) || empty($_POST['image']))
            ) {
                throw new Exception('Some of your fields are empty.');;
            }
                $filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
                $filetemp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['temp_name'];
                $filesize = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
                $filebasename = basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
                $dir="uploads/";
                $finaldir=$dir.$filebasename;
                move_uploaded_file($filetemp,$finaldir);

            // Prepare your Query and bind the parameters to the POST array
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO product (name, description, price, brand, image)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['desc'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['brand'], $_POST['image']);

            // Execute your query
            $stmt->execute();

            // Success!
            printf("<p class='msg success'>%s</p>", "Your record was created.");

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            // There was a problem
            printf("<p class='msg error'>%s</p>", $e->getMessage());

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please! Do provide anything relevant.

Comment: do you mean html code too?

Comment: Yes. If it's relevant. As well as CSS or more.

Comment: @Cyclone will you please elaborate?

Comment: @SummonaChefina - Edit your question and add the output of `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: do you mean i should write var_dump($_POST) in front of all these 
$_POST['name'], $_POST['desc'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['brand'], $_POST['image']);

Comment: @AllDani.com i guess php code i provided is sufficient for this problem. if you need something more..please tell ;)

Comment: I don't know php. I'm helping you help others help you.